# How to pass Node argument max-http-header-size to Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to increase the http request header size for my Firebase functions.
Normally, I can run `node --max-http-header-size <size> express.js` to increase the header limit if it is a usual Node service, but how I can do this to Firebase functions?